# C# LINQ Select Many

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am matching Cases to Controls, basically records in the Case list, need to have the number of matches that is specified in the string `m_ctrlno`.

So far I have two lists, the where clause is correct, however I'm unsure how to use `SelectMany` to get the 3 Controls that match 1 Case. I decided to use the `.Take()` function however it doesn't seem to be working. I'm not getting the same case with 3 different controls when i cycle on the var query.

Here is the code:

```
List<CaseSelection> CurrentCaseList = new List<CaseSelection>();
foreach (CaseSelection CurrentCase in m_casesarraylist)
CurrentCaseList.Add(CurrentCase);

List<ControlSelection> CurrentControlList = new List<ControlSelection>();
foreach (ControlSelection CurrentControlRec in ControlList)
CurrentControlList.Add(CurrentControlRec);


var query = CurrentCaseList.SelectMany(
c => CurrentControlList.Where(o => o.pracid == c.pracid && o.sex == c.sex &&
CaseSelectionList.AgeIsInRange(c.yob, o.yob, m_years)),
(c, o) =>
new { o, c }).Take(m_ctrlno);
```

Comment: Looks like you need `GroupBy` instead of `SelectMany`. Could you provide sample input and output, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code You define 2 list `CurrentCaseList,CurrentControlList` but not define `CaseSelectionList`.

To get the 3 controls that matches one case, for this see below code:

the `SelectMany` method to select all orders where `TotalDue` is less than 500.00.

Here is the code:

```
decimal totalDue = 500.00M;
using (AdventureWorksEntities context = new AdventureWorksEntities())
{
    ObjectSet<Contact> contacts = context.Contacts;
    ObjectSet<SalesOrderHeader> orders = context.SalesOrderHeaders;

    var query =
    contacts.SelectMany(
        contact => orders.Where(order =>
            (contact.ContactID == order.Contact.ContactID)
                && order.TotalDue < totalDue)
            .Select(order => new
            {
                ContactID = contact.ContactID,
                LastName = contact.LastName,
                FirstName = contact.FirstName,
                OrderID = order.SalesOrderID,
                Total = order.TotalDue
            }));

    foreach (var smallOrder in query)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Contact ID: {0} Name: {1}, {2} Order ID: {3} Total Due: ${4} ",
            smallOrder.ContactID, smallOrder.LastName, smallOrder.FirstName,
            smallOrder.OrderID, smallOrder.Total);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is ultimate solution @Santhosh. Thanks and Great.